# Displayport Hub functions like Apple Thunderbolt Display

Tags: usb, displayport

Does Displayport supports hub funtions for e.g. usb ([like the Apple Thunderbolt Display](https://www.apple.com/displays/))? 
I just bought an Dell XPS 13 2015 (9343), now running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr). 
It has a Mini Displayport 1.2 and it would be awesome to connect it to a external monitor and use its built-in usb hub. 
Displayport 1.2 in general supports [USB chaining](https://superuser.com/questions/363649/can-displayport-carry-usb).

The questions are now:

- Does Ubuntu supports such a feature?
- Are there even monitors (beside the Apple one) that support it?

Perhaps someone already uses such a setup. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised a question at [Ask Displayport](http://www.displayport.org/faq/ask-displayport/) and got the answer that Displayport 1.2 does NOT carry USB. Till now, USB 3.1 Type C (and Thunderbolt I guess) is the only technique.